# Encoding problems while making requests by batches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encoding, python-requests

I am making requests to an api:

```
def get_data(text, url='api.com'):
    r = requests.get(url,
                     params={'key': '<My KEY>',
                             'hj': text
                             'oi': 'm'})

    json_data = json.dumps(r.json())
    data = yaml.load(json_data)                
    return data
```

Then I am applying the function as follows, since my data is in a pandas dataframe:

```
    data
0   The quick  fox jumps over the lazy 
1   The quick  fox  over the lazy dog
2   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
....

n   The  brown fox jumps over the  dog
```

Then:

```
df['col'] = df[['data']].apply(get_data, axis=1)
```

The size of the data I am sending and receiving with requests is quite large, thus how can I make the above request by chunks?, let's say 4 by 4?:

```
for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=5):
       json_data = json.dumps(r.json())
       data = yaml.load(json_data)
       return data
```

However it aint worked, could some one help me to make the request by chunks or split in chunks and concat everything ?.

**UPDATE**

I also tried to split by chunks the dataframe, and it just doesnt finish:

In:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10)
for k,g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10):
    [g.data.apply(get_data) for _, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10)]
```

Out:

```
----> 7     df = pd.concat(g.data.apply(get_data) for _, g in df2.groupby(np.arange(len(df2))//4))
      8 df

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2290             else:
   2291                 values = self.asobject
-> 2292                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2293 
   2294         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:63307)()

<ipython-input-28-329dbdbb7cdb> in get_data(data)
     62 
     63     r = requests.get('http://api.example.com/api', params=payload, stream = True)
---> 64     json_data = json.dumps(r.json())
     65     data = yaml.load(json_data)
     66   

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    848                     # used.
    849                     pass
--> 850         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    851 
    852     @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, use_decimal, **kw)
    514             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None
    515             and not use_decimal and not kw):
--> 516         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    517     if cls is None:
    518         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w, _PY3)
    368         if _PY3 and isinstance(s, binary_type):
    369             s = s.decode(self.encoding)
--> 370         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
    371         end = _w(s, end).end()
    372         if end != len(s):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx, _w, _PY3)
    398             elif ord0 == 0xef and s[idx:idx + 3] == '\xef\xbb\xbf':
    399                 idx += 3
--> 400         return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

However I do not understand to chain everything together after splitting in chunks.

Comment: Maybe you can split `df.data` into chunks?

Comment: @Psidom, I updated my question with more details.. I actually tried that!

Comment: For your update, g will be a new data frame but smaller size, `g.data.apply(get_data)` would be one of the chunks.

Comment: @Psidom, how can I merge everything together again?

Comment: `[g.data.apply(get_data) for k,g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10)]` gives a list of all data. And then depending your actual data, you can make some transformation on it. Not sure what your data really is.

Comment: Thanks @Psidom, the data stored in the pandas dataframe is text, while the response of the request is a dict. Could you provide an answer just to give you the points?.

Comment: Few thoughts: (1) How big is your dataframe? (2) Why are you dumping from json and then loading back again? (3) How long does a single `request.get` take?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list comprehension to store the received files, here `g` will be the same as the original data frame but smaller size:

```
[g.data.apply(get_data) for _, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10)]
```

---

Or maybe what you are really looking for is, if you want to have a response for each text in the `data` series:

```
df.data.apply(get_data)
```

Note that `df[["data"]]` returns a data frame, so `df[["data"]].apply(get_data, axis = 1)` will pass the whole column to the `get_data` function.

Comment: Does `get_data(df.data.iloc[1])` finish soon? this passes only one text field and tries to get the response.

Comment: Hmm. even one request doesn't finish. It seems that you are doing some pos_tag but a simple sentence like this should finish instantly.

Comment: I will modify it to one, hold on!

Comment: I am confused since If I pass it a pandas dataframe of 5 instances it returns results...

Comment: What do you mean a data frame of 5 instances? How are you doing it? `df.data.loc[:5].apply(get_data)`? Or you want to pass the whole column to `get_data` at once instead of one value by another?

Comment: With the former!.. I guess if I pass all the data at once I will stuck this!